# Get summary of Toll and KM (by country and toll-system) with Fleet Telematics API and vehicleType BUS

Tags: here-api

Currently, our main purpose of using HERE services is to obtain KM per Country, as well as the Cost Price (costs of all types of tolls aggregated by country, by toll system, ...) of vehicle route.

For the most part, we’ve already figured out how to get all the information we need by calling the Fleet-telematics API ( https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html  ,     http://cre.api.here.com/swagger-ui.html?app_id=%7Byour-app-id%7D&app_code=%7Byour-app-code%7D#!/Routing_%26_Route_Matching/calculateRouteUsingPOST

), by

- setting vehicle-types (https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/vehicle-types-and-measures.html )
- setting of some other parameters, in particular "rollups" (to get "cost per country" and "cost per toll system" - https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html )

Our main focus is on buses (and a few cars). However, it seems we must use "TRUCK" instead of "BUS" as a "vehicle-type" otherwise we get an error ("bad request" - http status 400) out of your API endpoint.

Let me show you with an example.

by Truck:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?
apiKey=(REPLACE-API-KEY)
&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
&departure=2020-07-15T12:00:00
&alternatives=0
&currency=EUR
&tollVehicleType=3
&waypoint0=46.057745,14.507342
&waypoint1=stopOver!46.232389,15.262164
&waypoint2=stopOver!46.562957,15.638413
&waypoint3=stopOver!47.481128,18.99022
&waypoint4=50.066885,14.380644
&legAttributes=sm
&maneuverAttributes=none
&routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sc
&linkAttributes=none
&cost_optimize=0
&detail=1
&rollup=none,country;tollsys
```

by Car:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?
apiKey=(REPLACE-API-KEY)
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&departure=2020-07-15T12:00:00
&alternatives=0
&currency=EUR
&tollVehicleType=2
&waypoint0=46.057745,14.507342
&waypoint1=stopOver!46.232389,15.262164
&waypoint2=stopOver!46.562957,15.638413
&waypoint3=stopOver!47.481128,18.99022
&waypoint4=50.066885,14.380644
&legAttributes=sm
&maneuverAttributes=none
&routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sc
&linkAttributes=none
&cost_optimize=0
&detail=1
&rollup=none,country;tollsys
```

by Bus:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?
apiKey=(REPLACE-API-KEY)
&mode=fastest;bus;traffic:disabled
&departure=2020-07-15T12:00:00
&alternatives=0
&currency=EUR
&tollVehicleType=2
&waypoint0=46.057745,14.507342
&waypoint1=stopOver!46.232389,15.262164
&waypoint2=stopOver!46.562957,15.638413
&waypoint3=stopOver!47.481128,18.99022
&waypoint4=50.066885,14.380644
&legAttributes=sm
&maneuverAttributes=none
&routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sc
&linkAttributes=none
&cost_optimize=0
&detail=1
&rollup=none,country;tollsys
```

The only difference between all three URLs (requests) are the query parameters "mode" and "tollVehicleType".

While we use "TRUCK" and "CAR" inside query parameter "mode" the answer is OK (http status 200), but for "BUS" we get the following error:

```
{ "issues": [ { "message": "Router returned no route, error: 400 : {\"_type\":\"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType\",\"type\":\"ApplicationError\",\"subtype\":\"InvalidInputData\",\"details\":\"Invalid input parameter value\",\"additionalData\":[{\"key\":\"mode\",\"value\":\"fastest;bus;traffic:disabled\"}],\"metaInfo\":{\"timestamp\":\"2020-08-03T08:35:34Z\",\"mapVersion\":\"8.30.111.150\",\"moduleVersion\":\"7.2.202030-7513\",\"interfaceVersion\":\"2.6.76\",\"availableMapVersion\":[\"8.30.111.150\"]}}\n" }, { "message": "Request id: 360cf8bf-a542-4fa9-9198-436cf1c9dbfd" } ], "error_id": "360cf8bf-a542-4fa9-9198-436cf1c9dbfd", "response_code": "400 Bad Request" }
```

Only if we completely remove the query parameter "rollup" do we get the OK response for "BUS". But by doing so, we lose all the information we actually need (see the 1st paragraph).

An additional related question. What is the main difference between using "TRUCK" as a "vehicle-type" and "6" ("BUS") as a "tollVehicleType" OR by using "BUS" as a "vehicle-type" via query parameter "mode"*?

* - I assume that by using using "TRUCK" (as a "vehicle-type") and "BUS"("6") as a "tollVehicleType" you perhaps only remove tolls related to buses (e.g. there is no tolls on Germany highway/autobahn, but there is for trucks), but everything else (like regulations) is strictly related to trucks. On other hand by using "BUS" as a "vehicle-type" you probably also take into account EU and other BUS related regulations (as well as city limitations, e.g. prohibiting trucks but not buses). And this is very important feature to us - to plan routs correctly.

There is really not much description or examples specifically related to category BUS (as a "vehicle-type") in publicly available documentation, in general. We would be very happy if you have any internal publication available that you could share.